# Create dynamic function in oracle

Tags: oracle, function, dynamic, plsql, password-encryption

I have many tables with the same structure. One of the structure is given as follows: The table name is `TRACK_CONNECTION`.

Now i want to create dynamic function `decrypt_password_global` such that it can take dynamic input values and decrypt the password from table and return the value. I want to pass table_name,column_name,table_id,table_id_value in function as a input  parameter such that while executing the function decrypt_password_global for example for `TRACK_CONNECTION` table i will pass `(TRACK_CONNECTION,PASS,ID,11)`. In such way i can use decrypt_password_global function for other table also. I already created decrypt_password function for decrpytion of  password and it works fine. I just want to use `decrypt_password function` in `decrypt_password_global function` for decryption of value from table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build a SELECT-String and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE / INTO :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION decrypt_password( table_name IN varchar2,column_name IN varchar2,table_id varchar2,table_id_val varchar2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
     encrypted_pas varchar2(100);
     decrypted_pas varchar2(100);

   BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || column_name || ' from ' || table_name || ' where ' || table_id || ' = ' || table_id_val
         INTO encrypted_pas;
         Select decrypt_password(encrypted_pas) into decrypted_pas from dual;


  END decrypt_password;
```